# Do i need to add a plugin to every module in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using `ng-bootstrap` with angular 2. I have it imported in my `app.module` and it's working fine.

I am lazy-loading another module and `ng-bootstrap` components are not working in that. They work if I import ng-bootstrap module again in the lazy-loaded module.

My question is: Do I need to import 3-rd party modules again in every module I write or there is some way of making them to work by some setting ?

PS: I am a newbie to angular 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import a module in whatever module you want to use components, directives or pipes of the imported module. There is no way around it.

```
What you can do is to create a module that exports several other modules (like for example the `BrowserModule` that exports `CommonModule`.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CoolComponent, CoolDirective, CoolPipe],
  imports: [MySharedModule1, MySharedModule2],
  exports: [MySharedModule1, MySharedModule2, CoolComponent, CoolDirective, CoolPipe],
})
export class AllInOneModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [AllInOneModule]
})
class MyModule {}
```

This way you make everything exported by `AllInOneModule` available to `MyModule`.

Comment: So i can have my app.module (root module) export everything or it has to be a new separate module ?

Comment: I guess `AppModule` would work, but I wouldn't recommend it. Rather create a separate module.

Comment: you don't recommend it bcoz of performance issue or something else ?

Comment: Not because of performance. Just because of style. I wouldn't pack to much into a single module anyway. If things belong together and are supposed to be used together it's great, but just because you want only 1 import instead of 3 doesn't seem to provide much value. I find it valueable to see what a module depends on. If it depends on everything this is not useful information.

Comment: Agreed that we should be able to see what a module depends on.